# Woocommerce: Manual ordering of attribute values (not in numerical order)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

For my clients shoe business they have sizes from kids to adult.

For example in this product
http://pmfootwear.com/product/barcelona/

the attributes value’s should read 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2  but they read 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 13

Is there any way to control the ordering of attribute values and not have them default to numeric?

The attribute 'size' is set to custom ordering.

Thanks,
Joe

Link to attribute value screenshot & how 'size' attribute was set up: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbwobr6g0ozice4/Sizes1.jpg

Comment: give a screenshot of the product size attribute in your dashboard.  Where did you set the attribute to custom ordering ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I included a link above. Can't upload images as I don't have 10 reputation points yet!

Comment: I set the attribute to custom ordering when I originally set the attribute up in the attributes tab. You will see that the attribute values read 1 | 10 | 11 etc. They always default back to that when I click save even if I have changed them to the correct order, but on the front end they read 1 | 2 | 10 | 11 etc. So not sure how to have control over how they read. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the custom ordering, and set the attributes as per your requirement eg.  10|11|12|13|1|2  .  Try this by creating a new product. Woocommerce by default will show the variations in the order of the attributes as you set in the dashboard